# How to interpolate an expression <div id="here"></div> using ngFor index?

Tags: angular

I need to interpolate id="p + (i + 1)" and for="p + (i + 1) when I use ngFor

`

```js
<div class="terms-wrapper">
    <ul class="terms">
        <li class="terms-item" *ngFor="let item of [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]; let i=index">
            <input checked class="p-input" id="'p' + (i + 1)" type="checkbox" (change)="onChange($event)">
            <label class="p-label" for="'p' + i">{{"termsAgreement.paragraph_" + (i+1) + ".title" | translate}}</label>
            <h2 class="p-title">{{"termsAgreement.paragraph_" + (i+1) + ".title" | translate}}</h2>
            <p class="p-text">{{"termsAgreement.paragraph_" + (i+1) + ".text" | translate}}</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

{{"termsAgreement.paragraph_" + (i+1) + ".title" | translate}}
            {{"termsAgreement.paragraph_" + (i+1) + ".title" | translate}}
            {{"termsAgreement.paragraph_" + (i+1) + ".text" | translate}}
        
    
`

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is in the following example:

Use [for] property for data binding. Or you can use double brackets like {{'p'+ (i+1)}}

```js
<div class="terms-wrapper">
    <ul class="terms">
        <li class="terms-item" *ngFor="let item of [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]; let i=index">
            <input checked class="p-input" id="'p' + (i + 1)" type="checkbox" (change)="onChange($event)">
            <label class="p-label" [for]="'p' + i">{{"termsAgreement.paragraph_" + (i+1) + ".title" | translate}}</label>
            <h2 class="p-title">{{"termsAgreement.paragraph_" + (i+1) + ".title" | translate}}</h2>
            <p class="p-text">{{"termsAgreement.paragraph_" + (i+1) + ".text" | translate}}</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try property binding

```
[id]="'p' + (i + 1)"

[for]="'p' + i"
```

Answer (score 0):

Either try property binding as mentioned by @navnath, or try the following interpolation

```html
<input checked class="p-input" id="p{{i+1}}" type="checkbox" (change)="onChange($event)">

<label class="p-label" for="p{{i}}">
```